# Why do elemental DOT effects sometimes deal 1 damage each hit?

Tags: borderlands-2

This is an odd thing I've noticed with  Burn and Electrocute now; sometimes I'll get a solid hit on an enemy causing a Damage Over Time effect...but it does just 1 damage per "tick", causing a fountain of 1s, instead of 2000-4000 per, which my effects normally do at level 50.

It's not because the target resists it; I've seen it happen to Flesh enemies hit with Shock and Burn damage. And sometimes a target will take multiple normal DOT stacks and one or two "1 damage" stacks. So an enemy won't *always* be taking 1 damage per stack, one enemy that takes a 1 damage stack will suddenly take full damage the next stack, so it's not because of resistance, immunity or adaptive shields.

I've even noticed these 1 DPS effects on *myself* now, and not while using an immunity or adaptive shield. It was Fire so it should have done normal damage. Also, oddly enough, I've noticed *2* damage per "tick" DOT damage from my mechro on both Fire and Shock; I think that might be because her Shock DOT is boosted 75%, and her Fire DOT was caused by a skill which turns Shock DOT into extra Fire DOT. So it would seem the base power of the hit was somehow actually 1, amplified to a beefy 2.

What causes these super low damage DOT effects?

Comment: is this for pc?

Comment: @superdemongob yeah, on PC

Comment: What level is the gun you are using? I have had a lv 35 gun in my hands at lv 45 and hit a lv 47 target and the result was a scaled down dot of 1.

Comment: @BrandonBouquillon they're level 50. But lower level guns should still be well over 1 DOT, level 35 should still be causing hundreds of damage.

Comment: my guess is, maybe the NPC was using an adaptive or immunity shield?

Comment: @spartacus since the DOT *also* does normal damage on the same target without swapping weapons  that doesn't seem to be the case. Adaptives wouldn't reduce the damage to 1 anyway

Comment: maybe absorption shield then?  could be something funky going on with elemental damage and having the bullet absorbed

Comment: @spartacus not sure about that...absorbed bullet shouldn't cause damage, and if they don't cause damage I don't *think* they'll cause DOT but I'm not sure. Is there any way to visually tell if a bullet was absorbed?

Comment: its possible that they take full damage from effects when their shield is down, but when their shield is back up (i.e. recharging) they resist the element down to 1 damage per tick

Comment: @spartacus it's not that, I'm quite mindful of which element hits shields/flesh. It happens when their shields are down, and it happens with Shock which isn't resisted by either

Comment: About 4 days ago i had this happen when i shot the target practice bandit in sanctuary with a fire SMG. He does not wear a shield of any kind. I am stumped because he was level 22; the same level as my siren (who did the shooting) and the gun was only one level lower (req lv 21) and the dot was listed on the gun as being 130 something per sec.

Comment: I can also point out, that this is not a PC-only-issue. The same thing happened to me in the Xbox version of the game.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, hopefully this will be fixed in the near future.

Other people share your concerns: http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=182767

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely noticed this on the target dummy and occasionally in the round based levels. I only remmeber seeing it on smg/rifles. If you hit them with a longer burst of bullets you get full elemental damage. So I think it's like 1 or 2 bullets isn't always enough to light them up, but 3 or 4 causes the elemental to catch. Seen it with corrosive as well.